# Formula for subtracting time in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, time

I am trying to subtract time in and excel sheet.  For example, 8:58:43 (format hh:mm:ss)minus 0:43:48 minus 0:18:26.  I formatted each cell to be hh:mm:ss but I get a VALUE error when I have the formula =B3-C3-D3.  What formula would I use to get the data?
Thank you

Answer (score 4):

The formula is correct. If you get a #Value! error, at least one of the cells is text.

To find out which of the values is text, select all three values and format as General. The one that does not end up as a decimal number is the text value. Change it to a real time value. How to do that depends on what the problem is. There may be leading or trailing blanks, for example.

[image]